# error running sqlcmd using vim dbext though equivalent command runs manually

Tags: vim, sqlcmd, dbext

I am trying to use vim+dbext to run queries on an AzureSQL db using `sqlcmd`. The Result window shows an error:

```
    Connection: T(SQLSRV)  S([SERVER])  D([DB])  U([USER])   at 17:05
    job started:17:05:47 updates every 2000 ms
    To change connection parameters:
    :DBPromptForBufferParameters
    Or
    :DBSetOption user|passwd|dsnname|srvname|dbname|host|port|...=
    :DBSetOption user=tiger:passwd=scott
    Last command(rc=1):
    sqlcmd  -U [USER]  -P[PASS]  -S [SERVER]  -d [DB]  -i C:\Users\LOCAL_~1\Temp\dbext.sql
    Last SQL:
    select * from [TABLE] where [COL] = 'VALUE'
    go
    job ran for less than 2000 ms
```

If I run the command exactly as it appears manually in Command Prompt, it returns valid results. I believe sqlcmd is a 64 bit version. It's located in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE` and is in the path.

The dbext config for this profile is:

```
    let g:dbext_default_SQLSRV_bin = 'sqlcmd'
    let g:dbext_default_SQLSRV_cmd_options = ''
    let g:dbext_default_profile_[name] = 'type=SQLSRV:user=[USER]:passwd=[PASS]:dbname=[DB]:srvname=[SERVER]'
```

I tried this with and without the `cmd_options` line. How can I diagnose what is going wrong?